# How can long long int exist on 32-bit machines?

Tags: c, types, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit, long-long

I read that GCC supports the `long long int` type which is required to be at least 64 bits wide. But how can it make math operations with it on a CPU that is only 32 bits wide?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The compiler will synthesize math operations (or use function calls) that use more than one CPU instruction to perform the operation.  For example, an add operation will add the low order components (the low words) of the `long long` values and will then take the carry out of that operation and feed it into an add operation on the high order words of the `long long`.

So the following C code:

```
long long a;
long long b;
long long c;

// ...
c = a + b;
```

might be represented by an instruction sequence that looks something like:

```
mov eax, [a.low]   ; add the low order words
add eax, [b.low]

mov edx, [a.high]  ; add the high order words, 
adc edx, [b.high]  ; including the carry 

mov [c.low], eax
mov [c.high], edx
```

And if you consider for a moment, compilers for 8 and 16 bits systems had to do this type of thing for 16 and/or 32-bit values long before `long long` came into being.

Answer (score 11):

Internally, the type is represented by a high-word and a low-word, like:

```
struct long
{
  int32 highWord;
  uint32_t lowWord;
}
```

The compiler needs to know if it is a 32bit or 64bit environment and then selects the right reprenstations of the number - if it is 64bit, it can be done natively, if it is 32bit, the compiler has to take care of the math between the high/lowword.

If you have a look in math.h, you can see the functions used for this, and use them yourself. On an additional note, be aware of the difference between little-endian and big-endian ([see wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)), the usage depends on the operating system.

Comment: Two additional things: first, the order of this structure is machine order dependent.

Comment: Second, the function calls that operate on this structure are available to you. They are declared in math.h.

Comment: thirs the `lowByte` would really be `uint32_t` :-P

Comment: the term is 'word' not 'byte' in this context :)

Comment: Well, just one more, if it is a struct, how can I use it without any header file or so, just as any other datatype? (Visual C++ 2010 Express)

Comment: That its modelled as two 32-bit processor words is an internal detail of the compiler and not exposed to the programmer

Comment: @Joshua's comment should really be a part of the answer; it's a critical detail.

Comment: what exactly is this then? I did a quick google and nothing relevant came up. Isn't this the endianness stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Saying an architecture is 32 bit (or 64 or whatever) is usually only an approximation of what the processor is capable of. Usually you only refer to the width of pointers with that number, arithmetic might be quite different. E.g the x86 architecture has 32 bit pointers, most arithmetic is performed in 32 bit registers, but it also has native support for some basic 64 bit operations.

Also you shouldn't follow the impression that the standard integer types have some prescribed width. In particular long long is at least 64 bit but may be wider. Use the typedefs int32_t, int64_t if you want to be portably sure about the width.

If you want to know what gcc (or any other compiler) does with long long you have to look into the specification for your particular target platform

Answer (score 2):

It's easy enough to just compile and test if you have a 32-bit system accessible. gcc has a flag `-S` which turns on assembly language output. Here's what it produces on my 32-bit intel:

```
// read two long longs from stack into eax:edx and ecx:ebx
movl    32(%esp), %eax
movl    36(%esp), %edx
movl    24(%esp), %ecx
movl    28(%esp), %ebx
// a+b
addl    %ecx, %eax
adcl    %ebx, %edx
// a-b
subl    %ecx, %eax
sbbl    %ebx, %edx
// etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely as a class, not natively.  same way any compiler can/could support any large number set.

Answer (score 0):

A 32-bit processor can perform 32-bit operations in a single instruction.  64-bit operations require multiple instructions.

Machine word width is not a restriction on the size of data types - you could equally ask how 8 or 16 bit machines do arithmetic on larger types.  Clearly they can. They just do it in more CPU clock cycles.

For example when addition of the lower words of the operands overflows, the carry flag is set, then the high word result is the sum of the high words of the operands *plus 1* if the carry flag is set.  Example for an 8 bit machine (because it is easier as an example):

```
  Decimal    Binary
  1234       00000100    11010010
+ 4321       00010000  + 11100001
                |        --------
                |        10110011
                V       1 <--- carry flag 
             --------          |
           + 00010100 + 1 <----/
   ------------------------------
           = 00010101    10110011 ---> 5555 decimal --
                                                     |
= 5555  <--------------------------------------------/
```

For multiply, machines with a hardware multiplier (which is all modern 32 bit machines), the MUL instruction will have a double word result.  For example x86 `MUL EAX,r/m32` places the *64 bit* result in two 32 bit registers `EDX:EAX`.  Simpler processors without hardware multiply perform *long-multiplication* using multiple shift and addition instructions.  A *double-word x double-word* or *word x double-word* operation in either case requires multiple instructions.

You can of course synthesise operations from any number of words - hence how even 8-bit machines can perform 64 bit operations, albeit with more instructions and CPU cycles.

Also by extension, processors without a hardware FPU can perform floating-point math to single or double precision, and in fact arbitrary levels of precision are possible in software.