# How can I create a data structure for a 64 bit integer in a 32 bit architecture?

Tags: c, embedded, microprocessors

I am trying to make data structure for a 64 bit integer in a 32 bit  architecture.
Any idea to do this will be appreciate .

```
        struct make
        { 
            int a;// how to make  64 bit integer in a 32 bit  architecture.
         }
```

NOTE : I have a question, Will a C program compiled on a 32 bit Intel processor execute successfully on a 32 bit AMD processor?

Comment: You should post the second question separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a 
`long long`

On the IA32 architecture, 64-bit integer (`long long`) are implemented in using two 32-bit registers (eax and edx).

Comment: ,its really good answer. i like the way your explaining the context. can u give some example of using two 32-registers for generating 64 bit integer .

Comment: @SrinivasThanneeru see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072444/long-long-int-on-32-bit-machines

Comment: @SrinivasThanneeru:  You don't need to; the compiler does it for you.

Answer (score 3):

The `long long` datatype is usually 64 bits regardless of architecture.

Edit: with regard to your note, AMD and Intel processors use the same instruction set architectures. So, yes, a program compiled on an Intel chip should run on an AMD chip. (I assume you are talking about desktop cpus.)

Comment: I might be wrong, but strictly speaking `long long` is *at least* 64-bit. I would use `int64_t` from `<inttypes.h>`.

Comment: Whats the typedef of int64_t? I think the C standard only says that int<long<long long. It's just that mainstream operating systems have long long as 64 bits.

Edit: On OS X at least, int64_t reduces to `typedef long long int64_t`. I suspect it would be the same on other operating systems, however you are right. The int64_t type provides a nice worry free abstraction.

Comment: @zztops yes i am asking about the desktop cpus. what u said is impressive, now let me know what if they are using different instruction set arch's ?

Comment: It most definitely would not. The c code is compiled (assembly generated from c), assembled (object code generated from assembly), then linked (multiple object code filed merged together). I'm not really doing it justice here, but what actually gets executed by the processor differs drastically based on what ISA you compile on, not to mention operating system.

Comment: @MartinR: `int64_t` is defined in <stdint.h>.

Comment: @Clifford: You are right, thanks for the correction. - (I looked at some old code that for whatever reason included inttypes.h for that purpose.)