# Why are int and double the default Java primitives instead of long and double?

Tags: java

I have seen some similar questions here, but most of them are just people complaining about having to use long wrapper and such.

My question, more precisely, is if the width of a double is 64 bits and Java uses that as the default, why does Java still use int as a default (with a width of 32 bits) instead of long which also has a width of 64 bits?

If it were for memory concerns (which are not really a concern on most modern machines), why would they have not also set float as default instead of double?

It seems that they were okay with a 64 bit width on one hand but restricted the other to 32 bits and that just doesn't make much sense to me.

Thank you for any clarification!

Comment: Because Java was designed long before 64-bit processors became widespread, but even 32-bit processors supported double-precision floating point arithmetic. See [How does a 32-bit machine compute a double precision number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32167925/12299000)

Comment: Remember - Java was invented in the mid-90s.  When it was (mostly!) a 32-bit world :)  This was already an improvement over many compilers (e.g. C/C++), where "int" was commonly implemented as a 16-bit DOS "word".  16-bit Unicode was definitely an improvement over (near universal) 8-bit char.  And 2GB was a common file size/memory segment limitation ;)  ALSO: What do you mean by "the default"???

Comment: @Sweeper It is the default in the sense that `2.0` is a `double` literal rather than a `float` literal, and much of the standard library API (e.g. `Math.sqrt`) uses `double` rather than `float`.

Comment: Java always tries to keep backward compatibility.

Comment: *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic* - 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @paulsm4 I meant "default" in the sense that without the use of a suffix, Java assumes either int or double - like the example that kaya3 gave. I know Java was invented when 32-bit was more common but we are on Java SE 15 now and modern devices can easily handle 64-bit without any issue whatsoever. It just seems like it would be a simple update to the syntax.

Comment: @aran I fully understand the reason for using 64-bit floating point instead of 32-bit floating point. That wasn't really my question though. My real concern was, if we are okay with defaulting to 64-bit width for floating point, why can we not also just default to a 64-bit width integer now that devices are more than capable of handling it?

Answer (score 5):

There are no **default** numeric data types in Java.

In fact, the only case where the Java **language** shows any preference is in the syntax for integer and floating point literals ... where the literals mean `int` or `double` if you don't use a suffix.

And note that 64 bit floating point is preferred over 32 bit!!

> It seems that they were okay with a 64 bit width on one hand but restricted the other to 32 bits and that just doesn't make much sense to me.

Firstly, there is no such restriction.  This is just a **minor** syntax issue.

Secondly, the (slight) preference for `int` over `long` understandable, given that Java was originally designed when a lot of hardware didn't have good (fast) support for 64 bit integers.

The memory issue is also relevant too.  Note the first releases of Java didn't support 64 bit architectures at all.  On Intel / AMD, it wasn't available until Java 1.4.x.  And memory of that scale was not a "commodity" item.

> If it were for memory concerns (which are not really a concern on most modern machines), why would they have not also set float as default instead of double?

Because even in the 1990's they recognized that 32 bit floating point with only ~7-8 decimal digits of precision was problematic for most applications that need to use floating point.  This also explains why the `Math` API methods use `double` rather than `float` in most cases.

---

At any rate, the decisions to "prefer" `int` over `long` (as described above) were baked into the Java language over 20 years ago.  Changing this now would break source code compatibility for **billions** of lines of existing Java source code.  It won't happen.  Oracle's paying customers wouldn't let it happen.

Comment: I meant "default" in the sense that without a suffix, Java assumes int or double. I understand that 64 bit floating point is preferred - I just still don't understand why 32 bit integer would be preferred in this day and age. You would think that at some point between the creation of Java and Java SE 15, they would have switched to a syntax that assumes long when there is no suffix in order to simplify things a bit.

Comment: See the last paragraph.  The explanation is simple.  It would break too much existing code.  And everyone who learned Java prior to (say) Java 15 would have to **relearn** this.