# 32 bit operations on 8 bit architecture

Tags: c, 32-bit, 8-bit

I just want to ask you is it possible to get 32-bit operations on 8-bit architecture and if yes - how?

I thought about this for some time and the best idea I have is to `typedef char[N]` to get types from N byte size and then implement functions such as `add(char *, char *)`.

Thanks in advance!

(I'm using about the 6502 processor)

Comment: There are libraries for arbitrary width/precision math.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072444/long-long-int-on-32-bit-machines) this similar 32bit os calc 64bit long long int

Comment: It depends on your platform and your toolset which you didn't specify.

Comment: Check https://www.nand2tetris.org/ - it's good for building such fundamental understanding

Answer (score 4):

You have tagged your question as "C" so this answer takes this into consideration.

Most C compilers for 8-bit systems I know have `long` types. You can simply use these.

---

Having said this, how does it work?

All common 8-bit processors have a special 1-bit flag that receives the carry/borrow from 8-bit operations. And they have addition and subtraction instructions that take this flag into account. So a 32-bit add will be translated into this sequence:

```
    ; 1st operand in R0 to R3
    ; 2nd operand in R4 to R7
    ; addition works only with A(ccumulator)
    ; result goes into R0 to R3
    MOV     A,R0
    ADD     A,R4
    MOV     R0,A
    MOV     A,R1
    ADDC    A,R5
    MOV     R1,A
    MOV     A,R2
    ADDC    A,R6
    MOV     R2,A
    MOV     A,R3
    ADDC    A,R7
    MOV     R3,A
```

Think about how you do sums on paper. There is no need to add a carry on the rightmost digit, the least-significant one. Since there is "nothing" on the right, there is no carry. We can interpret each 8-bit step as one-digit operation on a digit of a number system of base 256.

For bit operations there is no need for a carry or borrow.

---

Another thought: What do you call an 8-bit system? When the instruction can just handle 8 bits in parallel, or when the data bus is just 8 bits wide?

For the latter case we can look at for example the 68008 processor. Internally a 32-bit processor its data bus has only 8 bits. Here you will use the 32-bit instructions. If the processor reads or writes a 32-bit value from/to memory it will generate 4 consecutive access cycles automatically.

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't quite understand why the first addition is done without carry. Could you explain?

Comment: Thanka you! Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Many (all that I know of...) CPUs have so called "carry flag" (1 bit), which is set when addition or substraction causes wrap-around. It is basically an extra bit for calculations. Then they have versions of addition and substraction, which include this carry flag. So you can do (for a example) 32-bit addition by doing 4 8-bit additions with carry.

Pseudocode example, little endian machine (so byte 0 of 4 byte result is the least significant byte):

```
carry,result[0] = opA[0] + opB[0]
carry,result[1] = opA[1] + opB[1] + carry
carry,result[2] = opA[2] + opB[2] + carry
carry,result[3] = opA[3] + opB[3] + carry
if carry == 1, overflow the 32 bit result
```

The first addition instruction might be called ADD (does not include carry, just sets it), while the following additions might be called ADC (includes carry and sets it). Some CPUs might have just ADC instruction, and reguire clearing the carry flag first.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the standard `int` / `long` types, the compiler will automatically do the right thing. `long` has (at least) 32 bit, so no need for working with carry bits manually; the compiler is already capable of that. If possible, use the standard `uint32_t`/`int32_t` types for readability and portability. Examine the disassembled code to see how the compiler deals with 32 bit arithmetics.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the answer to "Can I do M-bit arithmetic on a processor which has only N bits?" is "Certainly yes!"

To see why: back in school, you probably learned your addition and multiplication tables for only up to 10+10 and 10×10.  Yet you have no trouble adding, subtracting, or multiplying numbers which are any number of digits long.

And, simply stated, that's how a computer can operate on numbers bigger than its bit width.  If you have two 32-bit numbers, and you can only add them 8 bits at a time, the situation is almost exactly like having two 4-digit numbers which you can only add one digit at a time.  In school, you learned how to add individual pairs of digits, and process the carry -- and similarly, the computer simply adds pairs of 8-bit numbers, and processes the carry.  Subtraction and multiplication follow the same sorts of rules you learned in school, too.  (Division, as always, can be trickier, although the long division algorithm you learned in school is often a good start for doing long computer division, too.)

It helps to have a very clear understanding of number systems with bases other than 10.  I said, "If you have two 32-bit numbers, and you can only add them 8 bits at a time, the situation is almost exactly like having two 4-digit numbers which you can only add one digit at a time."  Now, when you take two 32-bit numbers and add them 8 bits at a time, it turns out that you're doing arithmetic in base 256.  That sounds crazy, at first: most people have never heard of base 256, and it seems like working in a base that big might be impossibly difficult.  But it's actually perfectly straightforward, when you think about it.

(Just for fun, I once wrote some code to do arithmetic on arbitrarily big numbers, and it works in base 2147483648.  That sounds *really* crazy at first -- but it's just as reasonable, and in fact it's how most arbitrary-precision libraries work.  Although actually the "real" libraries probably use base 4294967296, because they're cleverer than me about processing carries, and they don't want to waste even a single bit.)