# How does a 32 bit processor support 64 bit integers?

Tags: c++, integer

In C++, you can use an `int` which is usually 4 bytes. A `long long` integer is usually 8 bytes. If the cpu was 32 bit, wouldn't that limit it to 32 bit numbers? How come I can use a `long long` integer if it doesn't support 64 bits? Can the alu add larger integers or something?

Comment: See Knuth Vol 2, section 4.3

Comment: [How is 64-bit math accomplished on a 32-bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3190143/995714)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most processors include a carry flag and an overflow flag to support operations on multi-word integers. The carry flag is used for unsigned math, and the overflow flag for signed math.

For example, on an x86 you could add two unsigned 64-bit numbers (which we'll assume are in EDX:EAX and EBX:ECX) something like this:

```
add eax, ecx  ; this does an add, ignoring the carry flag
adc edx, ebx  ; this adds the carry flag along with the numbers
; sum in edx:eax
```

It's possible to implement this sort of thing in higher level languages like C++ as well, but they do a lot less to support it, so the code typically ends up substantially slower than when it's written in assembly language.

Most operations are basically serial in nature. When you're doing addition at the binary level, you take two input bits and produce one result bit and one carry bit. The carry bit is then used as an input when adding the next least significant bit, and so on across the word (known as a "ripple adder", because the addition "ripples" across the word).

There are more sophisticated ways to do addition that can reduce that dependency between one bit and another when a particular addition doesn't produce a dependency, and most current hardware uses such things.

In the worst case, however, adding `1` to a number that's already the largest a given word size supports will result in generating a carry from every bit to the next, all the way across the word.

That means that (to at least some extent) the word width a CPU supports imposes a limit on the maximum clock speed at which it can run. If somebody wanted to badly enough, they could build a CPU that worked with, say, 1024-bit operands. If they did that, however, they'd have two choices: either run it at a lower clock speed, or else take multiple clocks to add a single pair of operands.

Also note that as you widen operands like that, you need more storage (e.g., larger cache) to store as many operands, more gates to carry out each individual operation, and so on.

So given identical technology, you could have a 64-bit processor that ran at 4 GHz and had, say, 4 megabytes of cache, or a 1024-bit processor that ran at about 250 MHz and had, perhaps, 2 megabytes of cache.

The latter would probably be a win *if* most of your work was on 1024-bit (or larger) operands. Most people don't do math on 1024-bit operands very often at all though. In fact, 64-bit numbers are large enough for most purposes. As such, supporting wider operands would probably turn out to be a net loss for most people most of the time.

Comment: So how come you can't have 128 bit integers? Or even 256 bit? I know there are classes for that, but why can't the computer do that in the first place?

Comment: @user3452725 They can, you just have to tell them to - by chaining these carry instructions.

Comment: @user3452725: Adding is fundamentally a serial operation--adding the two least significant bits generates a result bit *and* a carry bit that's used as an input when adding the next least significant bits. There are optimizations to reduce that dependency, but in the worst case you can have carries all the way across, so it's unavoidable. So while they could support wider words in single operations, doing so would reduce speed, and most people don't use 128-bit or 256-bit numbers very often. Similar considerations apply to subtraction, multiplication, etc.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to support arbitrarily wide integers (through software implementation), even if the underlying hardware only supports less bits directly. If a 32-bit integer is added to another 32-bit integer, it could overflow and require 33 bits to store the answer. Software can detect that this overflow occurred (the processor has a [carry flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag) that can be checked), and another 32-bit word that represents the most significant bits of the 64-bit number can be incremented by 1.

[Here's a little more](http://brodowsky.it-sky.net/2013/12/22/carry-bit-how-does-it-work/) on the carry flag and how it's used.

Answer (score 5):

Essentially the normally single instruction add is broken into two (or three) steps:

1)  Add the low-order 32 bits using the usual add instruction.  Note whether this addition would generate a "carry out" bit (that is, if the result would actually require 33 bits to represent).

2) Add the high order 32 bits the same way.  If there was a carry-out from the lower order bits, set the carry in bit here (or, alternatively, add one to the result after adding).

Answer (score 4):

You use two memory locations to store the number.  Half of the number is stored at one location in memory, and the other half in the adjacent memory location.

Comment: Well, that depends on what you're trying to do.  Say you're adding two numbers:

you add the low order parts first, and then add the top order parts with any carry that was generated.

Comment: If you want to know more, it might be a good idea to learn Assembly code.

Comment: @user3452725 integers can't be rounded, since they're always a whole number.

Comment: @Steve Sorry I meant carry

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider that we used to cope with 16 or even 32 bit sized integers back in the days of 8-bit CPUs. There's nothing that restricts any particular alu from handling arbitrary size numbers other than memory space and ultimately I suppose the patience of the user.

Smalltalk for example has always provided arbitrary length integers since the original Dorados and Altos - that takes us back to 1970. Want the exact value of 963! - just do it. It'll take a while to format it to print though.