# How are long integers processed in 64 bit computers? How can I determine the size of an object?

Tags: java, object, long-integer, primitive, bit

**Q1**: If my computer has 32-bit processor, how does `long` type which is 64-bit be stored and used for processing?
On the other hand, if I am using only `int` types in my 64-bit processor, am I not wasting 32-bits of memory?

**Q2**: For primitives, we say `byte` is 8-bit, `int` is 32-bit. How do we say the same for objects? Is there a way to get the size of objects in Java. or what is the maximum size an object can be?

Comment: Please clarify your questions; **1** It is a virtual machine. **2** Yes. Serialize it to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and get the length of the array when you're done... but why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate size of Object in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368764/calculate-size-of-object-in-java)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object

Comment: "The external address and data buses are often wider than 32 bits but both of these are stored and manipulated internally in the processor as 32-bit quantities." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the second question, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object).

For the first question, 32-bit processors cannot *directly* deal with 64-bit integers as 64-bit operands cannot be stored in 32-bit registers "as a whole". Compilers solve this issue by transforming 64-bit operations into a series of operations on 32-bit operands which represent halves of 64-bit operands. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2692369/671092) for a thorough explanation.

In Java, `long` is guaranteed to be exactly 64 bits, `int` is guaranteed to be exactly 32 bits. Using 64-bit integers on a 32-bit machine probably impacts performance, but given the nature of Java I don't think this would be pretty much noticeable (maybe in number crunching applications).

Answer (score 2):

Java has fixed sized data type, *intentionally*. Where in C `int` may vary in size, with java int always is signed 32 bits. So the remaining questions concern the implementation.

And that may vary. But looking at the JVM byte code instructions there are some decisions made. A local variable of type `byte` may be stored in an int (32 bits). And so on. Also Oracle 64 bits java has an option to use not 64 bits for object references but 32 bits, saving hugely in memory.

Comment: can you explain how long which is 64 bit is stored in 32-bit processor

Comment: As two 32 bits words, and if the processor has no 64 addition, two 32 bit additions are done. Java byte code is primarily interpreted, and with a just-in-time hotspot compiler translated to machine code. As almost any full fledged programming language it can do all. There are JVMs for 16 bit processors (maybe no more).