# Firebase server timestamp and non 64 bit device: Integer literal '...' overflows when stored into 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, 32bit-64bit, iphone-64bit

I have stored messages in Firebase like so:

```
messageObject["timestamp"] = FIRServerValue.timestamp()
```

The objects have a child like: `timestamp: 1465222757817`. The problem is that older non 64 bit devices cannot handle Integers of that length. What would be a good workaraound for this problem?

**Edit:**

When declaring the timestamp as `Int64`, it throws an error:

```
var timestampQueryValue: Int64 = 1465222757817
self.chatRef.queryOrderedByChild("timestamp")
    .queryStartingAtValue(timestampQueryValue)
    .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { 
        (snapshot) -> Void in /* ... */ })

/* Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Int64' 
          to expected argument type 'AnyObject?' */
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692329/int64-on-a-32-bit-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly deal with larger numbers, even on 32 bit devices, if you explicitly specify `UInt64` or `Int64` (unsigned, and signed, respectively).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I cannot use the value fore Firebase queries then. See updated question.

Comment: Perhaps it's expected to be wrapped in an instance of `NSNumber`?

Comment: `NSNumber(longLong: timestampQueryValue)` worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*(This answers the edited question: error when explicitly using the `Int64` type)*

Given your error message, it would seems as if the method `.queryStartingAtValue(...)` expects type `AnyObject?`, which will allow using, as argument, *types automatically (implicitly) bridgeable to `AnyObject`*, which explains why you don't have this issue with the `Int` type, whereas you do with the `Int64` type.

- [Interoperability - Working with Cocoa Data Types - Numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html)

I.e., the former (`Int`) is automatically bridged to a Obj-C/Cocoa class type (`NSNumber`) whereas this automatic bridging is not natively accessible for the latter (`Int64`).

There's two ways to redeem this

1. Explicitly perform the bridging from `Int64` to the equivalent `NSNumber` type, using the `NSNumber` initializer `init(longLong: <Int64>)`

   ```
   let foo: Int64 = 1465222757817
   let bar = NSNumber(longLong: foo)
   ```

   I.e., in your example, you could attempt the following:

   ```
   //...
       .queryStartingAtValue(NSNumber(longLong: timestampQueryValue))
   ```
2. Or, using undocumented features (that might break in the future): conform `Int64` to the internal protocol `_ObjectiveCBridgeable`, to allow the same implicit `NSNumber` bridging as is available for `Int` type. The following threads explains exactly this implementation:

   - [Is it possible to replicate Swifts automatic numeric value bridging to Foundation (NSNumber) for (U)Int8/16/32/64 types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893517/is-it-possible-to-replicate-swifts-automatic-numeric-value-bridging-to-foundatio)

   After implementing this implicit bridging for `Int64`, your existing code should work as is, as the `Int64` argument to `.queryStartingAtValue(...)` will be automatically converted to the appropriate `NSNumber` (class) type.